# Append/Link HTML file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been looking for a way to insert HTML from an another HTML file (saved locally) - But important **without Jquery** or other libraries. Basically what I am trying to do is refactor from this:

#### First Approach (is working)

```
public setForm(): void {
        this.appDiv.innerHTML = `<form id="registerForm">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign up</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control mt-1" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <button id="registerButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>`;
    }
```

to something like this:

#### Refactored version

```
public setForm(): void {
    this.appDiv.innerHTML = document.insertFromPath('./views/register-panel.html').innerHTML;
}
```

#### Why do I want to do this?

Not only that the code looks cleaner. It allows me to encapsulate logik and each file has its own "responsibility". Javascript files tend to get messy.^^

Comment: I am not able to find any method called `insertFromPath` over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#Methods
Where did you get that from?

Comment: This is just a suggestion.^^ Maybe I should mention this. But maybe there is a method along those lines.

Comment: so you're trying to create a templating engine? like pug or ejs? If you're doing this for fun and learning then I'd find resources on how to do this on google, if you're trying to actually get work done, just use an existing templating engine because those take a long time to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [object](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp) tag.

```
<object data="/views/register-panel.html"> 
    Your browser doesn’t support the object tag. 
</object>
```

**NOTE:** I have used the filepath you have provided. Please ensure your filepath is correct by checking your project structure.

Comment: Even though your approach is working I feel like the loading is slow in comparison to my first approach and the linked html is not applying css classes...

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution and use `your ID` instead of `content`

```
function setForm() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="/views/register-panel.html" ></object>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your .js cleaner, you can set a template in your html and consume it with Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template